# Background worker while loop

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to create is a background worker that executes a few processes every 30seconds.  But I want this while loop to execute for as long as the program is launched.  here is what I am using:

```
    private void watcherprocess1()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }  
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while(
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        specficView2();
        makeFormlist2();
        populateListview2();
    }
```

My main issue is ai can think of a good while loop to keep this running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
while(true)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think a [Timer from the Threading-Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) would be much better suited for this. It will tick asynchron, and you can spawn of the process from the Tick-Event.

Comment: ...if the work might take more than the interval (30 seconds), you might want to set the timer at the end of the work adjusting for the time spent in the current work unit. Else your background workers may overlap and there can be many running at the same time. Oftentimes, this is something to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Comment: Keep in mind this will execute the event on the UI thread: `A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.`

Comment: @Justin: in this case, given the names of the methods in question, this may actually be the best alternative...

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to point this out since it is an important distinction between this and the Threading timer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Bobby that a System.Threading.Timer (or a System.Timers.Timer) is probably best suited to this job.

But if you *must* create a use a worker thread, I'd rather create one specially for the task. Running a BackGroundWorker (which is a ThreadPool Thread) is a while loop *for the lifetime of your application* doesn't sit well with me.

Maybe something like this:

```
private void watcherprocess1()
{        
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Work));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Name = "My Worker.";
    thread.Start();
}  

private void Work()
{
    while(true)
    {            
        specficView2();
        makeFormlist2();
        populateListview2();
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```