# C# background worker and timer loop

Tags: c#

This is my first attempt of a Timer, if someone could help me out where I am going wrong it would be awesome.

I'm trying to use a while loop where if the timer hits 30 seconds try to loop it again.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer my_timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        my_timer = null;
        //int restartticker = 30000;
        while (true)
        {
            my_timer.Start();
            if (my_timer.Equals(30000))
            {
                watcherprocess1();
            }
            my_timer = null;
        }
    }
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  my_timer.Start();

Comment: >.> you are setting `my_timer = null;` immediately following instantiation. hence `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Think logically, why would you get an `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: In fact you're setting `my_timer = null;` twice, once before the loop and again in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is caused by you setting the Timer to null, to solve that just remove `my_timer = null;` (2x).

But a Timer is not well suited for 'pausing' a Thread (BGW). A simple solution looks like:

```
    while (true)
    {
         Thread.Sleep(30000);
         watcherprocess1();
    }
```

#### Edit:

I spotted your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579648/c-background-worker-while-loop). The consensus (but not the accepted answer) was the advice to use a Timer *instead* of a Backgroundworker, not *inside* a Backgroundworker.

Comment: I think you are pretty close to what he needs, unless I am missing something.

Comment: What if the watcherprocess takes more than some infinitesimal amount of time to run, like 1.5 seconds, but he needs it to run every 3 seconds?  In that case, he'd want to sleep for 1.5 seconds, not 3 seconds, and keeping track of that would be painful.  hence the need for a timer rather than a sleep.

Comment: @mmr, he would need a Stopwatch + another loop, not a Timer. But I'm not going to speculate that far ahead.

Answer (score 2):

It's these lines (and you should remove them):

```
my_timer = null;
```

Without code comments, I can't give you a decent alternative (i.e., I have no idea why you'd be doing that in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a `Timer` object, and then immediately setting it to `null`?

You should subscribe to the [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) event, and put your code in there. It should automatically loop every thirty seconds if you set its interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely incorrect attempt to use the Timer class. `my_timer.Equals(30000)` will NEVER evaluate to true, because Timer doesn't override `Object.Equals()`.

If you want to do something when the timer hits 30 seconds, you have to set `my_timer.Interval` to 30000 and then subscribe to the `my_timer.Tick` event.

You might like to have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdh6857z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for the Timer class.

And as everyone else said, don't do `my_timer = null`.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the timer and then set it back to null:

```
my_timer = null;
```

Which means when you call `my_timer.Start()` there is no value for my_timer...hence the Exception.

Unfortunately, without some kind of better idea what you're trying to accomplish, we're not going to be able to help you with better code to get the job done.