# Running javascript tests from .net unit tests

Tags: javascript, .net, unit-testing, msbuild, jstestrunner

I have working CI/CD pipeline using MSBuild with "run unit tests" step and separated build server for this.
Its pretty hard to instal other tools like karma or npm for running javascript tests separately, so I want to run all javascript tests from .net unit test.

So, basically I want to create something like

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var file = LoadJSFile();

    // how can I impleemnt this method?
    RunJSTests(file);
}
```

So, I have two questions:
1. Are there any existing tools for this (like nuget package)?
2. Maybe, I'm going in totally wrong direction and I should spend my efforts to creating separate CI step "Run Javascript Tests"?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feel is that in the long run a separate CI step for the JavaScript tests would be better, but there's some ideas you could investigate / follow from this post [How to run QUnit test and get back test result in C# via JavaScript callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108897/how-to-run-qunit-test-and-get-back-test-result-in-c-sharp-via-javascript-callbac).

The reason I suggest a separate CI step is to decouple the JS from the C#, so that if in the future you switched from pure JS to, say, Angular or typescript, the migration of tests would be simpler. Similarly any migration of C# to F# or, more likely, MSBuild to Jenkins or other CI server could be done more flexibly.

If there's little bingle info for option 1 then that suggests option 1 is somewhat niche, but I don't want to pre-judge that, but if so go with option 2 for now - you can always implement option 1 in the future if necessary and feasible.